# Angular <img [src]="getImg()"> called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to understand what is happening here. I created a new Angular project, in app.component.html:

```html
<img [src]="getDemoImg()">
```

app.component.ts:

```js
getDemoImg(){
  console.log('why so many logs???');
  return 'https://historia.nationalgeographic.com.es/medio/2019/12/11/coliseo-roma_2924b6ae_1280x720.jpg'
}
```

console.log is printing 4 times that message, it seems the function is called 4 times, what is wrong here?

reproducible example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d5hdmo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I think it's better to use pipes in angular to fix this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, all functions in your html will be called when change detection runs. Many things can cause change detection to run, and when it does run the framework will recheck all of the variables in your html to see if they changed.

There is no way to know that your function won't return something different each time, so if the framework is checking for changes, it needs to call the function again in order to make sure your html is up to date.

You need to be very careful when calling functions directly in html as opposed to attaching them to an event, especially if those functions take lots of time or make http requests. You might end up bogging down your application, or worse - requesting way too much data from a pay as you go database.

The default behaviour is to check the entire component tree every time something happens that could've changed some data somewhere. Examples: browser events (click, mouseover), `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()`, and more. In development mode, change detection is run twice in a row back to back, to ensure nothing was changed *during* change detection. So in production you would see the log once on the initial load, and then once again because something is triggering change detection - to be honest I'm not sure exactly what is triggering it.

---

If you want to disable automatic change detection on a component you can use the `OnPush` strategy:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: ...
})
export class MyComponent {
```

Now your html will only re-render if you explicitly invoke change detection, or if an `@Input()` variable is changed.

```
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  refresh() {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

Example with the `OnPush` strategy:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z39ayo?file=src/app/app.component.ts

More info on change detection:

https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a variable to binding src or another attribute and update the variable if you need.